# Differential forms and hairy ball theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, differential-forms, de-rham-cohomology

Take the $2$-form $\omega = \sin\phi \,\mathrm d \phi \wedge \mathrm d \theta$ in spherical coordinates, defined on the portion of $\mathbb R^3$ outside of the unit sphere. Clearly, $\omega$ is closed but not exact. I was wondering if there exists a clear link between this fact and the hairy ball theorem.

Comment: Nope. Think of replacing $S^2$ with $S^1$. Can you construct a closed non-exact form?

Comment: Yes. So it has nothing to do with the dimensionality, which is the case for the hairy ball theorem. Right?

Comment: Right. Actually, the HB theorem is a special case of the Poincare-Hopf index theorem which says that for every vector field $X$ (with isolated zeroes) on a closed manifold $M$, $ind(X)=\chi(M)$. If $X$ has no zeroes then $ind(X)=0$, hence, $\chi(M)=0$. In the case of spheres, the dimension appears due to the fact that $\chi(S^n)=1+(-1)^n$.

Answer (score 4):

You can prove the hairy ball theorem also using forms. You can see a tangent vector field as a smooth map $F:S^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ such that
$$
\langle F(x),x \rangle=0, \, \, \mbox{for all } x\in S^2,
$$
where $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is the standard scalar product of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Suppose you have a never vanishing vector field $F$, then you can normalize it
$$
\bar{F}:=\frac{F}{||F||},
$$
so you can see it as (smooth) map $\bar{F}:S^2\rightarrow S^2$. If yuo have such a map you can perform a (smooth) homotopy between the identity $id_{S^2}$ and the antipodal map $-id_{S^2}$. Condier the map $G:S^2\times [-1,1]\rightarrow S^2$ given by
$$
G(x,t):=\cos(t\pi)x+\sin(t\pi) \bar{F}(x).
$$
Fix a volume form $\omega$ for $S^2$ (it is a closed form), then because $G$ is an homotopy between the identity $id_{S^2}$ and the antipodal map $-id_{S^2}$ you have (note that $id_{S^2}^{\ast}(\omega)=\omega$)
$$
\int_{S^2}\omega=\int_{S^2}-id_{S^2}^{\ast}(\omega)
$$
Because 2 is even (as you can guess this proof works for any even dimensional sphere) the antipodal map $-id_{S^2}$ is the composition of an *odd* number of reflections (you have $S^2\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ so you have to do 3 reflections in order to have $-id_{S^2}$). Then you have 
$$
vol(S^2)=\int_{S^2}\omega=\int_{S^2}-id_{S^2}^{\ast}(\omega)=-\int_{S^2}\omega=-vol(S^2)
$$
That is a contraddiction because for any volume form $\omega$ the volume of $S^2$ is non zero. So you can not have such a never vanishing tangent vector field $F$.